# In sequelize connection I am getting operation timeout error. How to fix this issue?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run node JS server & Postgres inside docker & using sequalize for DB Connection. However, Seems like my Node JS Server is not able to communicate with Postgres DB inside docker.

Before someone mark it as Duplicate, Please note that I have already checked other answers & none of them worked out for me.
I already tried implementing Retry Strategy for Sequalize connection.

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  rapi:
    container_name: rapi
    image: rapi/latest
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    environment:
      - EXTERNAL_PORT=3001
      - PGUSER=rapiuser
      - PGPASSWORD=12345
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGHOST=rapi_db # NAME OF THE SERVICE
    depends_on:
      - rapi_db
  rapi_db:
    container_name: rapi_db
    image: "postgres:12"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=rapiuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    volumes:
      - rapi_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  rapi_data: {}
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16

EXPOSE 3000

# Use latest version of npm
RUN npm i npm@latest -g

COPY package.json package-lock.json* ./
RUN npm install --no-optional && npm cache clean --force

# copy in our source code last, as it changes the most
WORKDIR /
COPY . .

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

My DB Credentials:

```
credentials = {
        PGUSER :process.env.PGUSER,
         PGDATABASE :process.env.PGNAME,
         PGPASSWORD : process.env.PGPASSWORD,
         PGHOST : process.env.PGHOST,
         PGPORT:process.env.PGPORT,
         PGNAME:'postgres'
        }
        console.log("env Users: " + process.env.PGUSER + " env Database: " + process.env.PGDATABASE + " env PGHOST: " + process.env.PGHOST + " env PORT: " + process.env.EXTERNAL_PORT)
}
//else credentials = {}
module.exports = credentials;
```

Sequalize DB code:

```
const db =  new Sequelize(credentials.PGDATABASE,credentials.PGUSER,credentials.PGPASSWORD, {
  host: credentials.PGHOST,
  dialect: credentials.PGNAME,
  port:credentials.PGPORT,
  protocol: credentials.PGNAME,
  dialectOptions: {
  },
  logging: false,
  define: {
    timestamps: false
  }
  ,
   pool: {
      max: 10,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 100000,
   },
   retry: {
    match: [/Deadlock/i, Sequelize.ConnectionError], // Retry on connection errors
    max: 3, // Maximum retry 3 times
    backoffBase: 3000, // Initial backoff duration in ms. Default: 100,
    backoffExponent: 1.5, // Exponent to increase backoff each try. Default: 1.1
  },
});
  module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your process.env.PGPORT does not exists. Add an enviroment variable in the docker-compose for service rapi or set it to 5432 in your credentials file.